# Selenium WebDriver doesn't drive Privacy box in Kayak web site

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

[image]

I test automated a test case in Selenium `WebDriver`. The driver opens [Kayak UK web site](https://www.kayak.co.uk/flights) in incognito mode. However it doesn't drive privacy popup.
I was wondering what line of codes do I need to include to Accept the box? I checked and the message box is not in `iFrame`. I tested

```
SwitchTo().Alert().Accept
```

and it didn't work. Not sure, what it is that Web Driver doesn't drive it.

Any tips/suggestions/advises much appreciated.

Comment: Add your code. Read [How to create a Minimal, **Complete**, and **Verifiable** Example.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I guess the box is **not** an `alert()` box. Add the link to kayak too

Comment: I cannot investigate what type it is. It is also not a second window. The privacy message box appears when i open https://www.kayak.co.uk/flights in incognito mode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you right click on the `No thanks` button, then `Inspect`, you can see:

```html
<button role="button" class="Iqt3 Iqt3-mod-stretch Iqt3-mod-bold Button-No-Standard-Style Iqt3-mod-variant-outline Iqt3-mod-theme-base Iqt3-mod-shape-rounded-small Iqt3-mod-shape-mod-default Iqt3-mod-spacing-default Iqt3-mod-size-small" tabindex="0" aria-disabled="false"><div class="Iqt3-button-container"><div class="Iqt3-button-content">No thanks</div></div><div class="Iqt3-button-focus-outline"></div></button>
```

You just have to click the following [xpath](/questions/tagged/xpath):

```
//button[contains(., "No thanks")]
```

in the Dev Tools:

```
$x('//button[contains(., "No thanks")]')[0].click()
```

This is **not** an `alert()` box. That's why it fails.

---

There are many resources available online to learn `XPath`. Here are some that can helps to get started:

- [W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_intro.asp) covers all the basics of XPath with suitable examples and...
- [W3Schools XPath syntax](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_syntax.asp)
- [Tutorialspoint](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/xpath/index.htm) explains the basics of XPath and is suitable for beginners.